# automatically print large numbers of pdfs with laravel in background job

Tags: php, laravel, printing, laravel-5.4, amazon-sqs

We run our App with Laravel 5.4 with a worker, redis and sqs for our Jobs.

Now we got a feature request, where we need to print a large number of tickets (around 3,000 tickets) as a batch. 
Tickets are generated as PDF (filesize: 500kb per ticket). Which would add up to 1,5gb for 1 batch.

**Our idea at the moment:**

*When user clicks on create tickets an event will be fired which will generate all pdfs as a background job and will save all files into an s3 bucket, zips them and user gets an alert when its ready. 
user gets a link to download the zip file and can print them.*

With downloading them, user always need to select some amount of tickets and print them. This is not the preferred solution.

**Is there any other possibility?**

Can I send such a job directly to the user's printer, so that user does not need to sit in front of the computer until the printing job is done?

Comment: Is this customer's printer connected to the internet with an API or service?

Comment: I dont think so. But if that will be of help, we will try to recommend our customers new printers with that ability

Comment: I don't know if there are printers like that, you'd have to do some research. For the time being they'll have to wait for the downloads and then send them to a printer manually.

Comment: I have seen that for example HP printers have some kind of e-service, where they can be attached to a web service. I also need to dig into that further.

Comment: Your title and question do not match very well. Reading the title I expected to see a complaint about how slow PDF generation is but your question is about how to automatically send print jobs to a printer...

Comment: Is the target printer always at the office? Would the user ever expect this to print to their home printer or some on-site printer away from the office?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I changed the subject a little bit, thanks. 
the target printer will be always at home or in the office. connected with usb to the laptop/pc they are working on.

Answer (score 1):

If your printer supports google cloud printing you can send your print jobs through the google cloud print api. For more information on the google cloud print api see [google cloud print api](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appDevGuide). You can also make a "classic" printer google cloud print ready, see [here](https://www.google.com/landing/cloudprint/).

Another option is  [Printnode](https://www.printnode.com/), but that is a paid plan.

Comment: Thank you. We will look at this!